# Влияние nextpage на индексацию

Tags: wordpress, поисковые-системы

Как поисковые системы относятся к тегу `<!--nextpage-->` в *WordPress*?
Сколько результатов будет в выдаче, если, например, статья разделена на 2 части?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здравствуйте. Никто не дал ответа, поэтому ждал индексацию.

**Вот что получилось:** статья поделена на 3 части. В выдаче **google** появились 3 отдельные странички вида www.site/article, www.site/article/2/ и www.site/article/3/.
**Title** статьи не изменился (хотя я думал, что будет приписываться порядковый номер к каждой её части).

*Возможно вам пригодится полученная информация, и Вам не придётся что-то переделывать.*